# cannot switch workspaces in unity desktop

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity desktop. I'm using a 4×4 desktop matrix. I can switch between the desktops horizontally only. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(left/right)</kbd> works, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(up/down)</kbd> doesn't.

It is fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation. Only `unity-desktop` and `unity-tweak-tool` were installed. Keyboard works.

Is something eating the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>up/down</kbd> shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was, that by default is switching desktops vertically realized by Ctrl+Alt+PgDn/PgUp and not by Ctrl+Alt+Down/Up arrows. It can be easily changed in keyboard shortcuts settings.